# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to map locations on real map.

```
sbbox <- make_bbox(lon = New_Ts$Hotel_Longitude, lat = New_Ts$Hotel_Latitude, f = .1)
sbbox

mapgilbert <- get_map(location = sbbox, maptype = "roadmap")
ggmap(mapgilbert) + geom_point(data = New_Ts, mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red")
```

It works when I tried on Rstudio console but when I do Knit from Rmarkdown. It gives me following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... by_layer -> f -> <Anonymous> -> f -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN

Execution halted
```

I tried to delete "lon" object and did again knit but still it gives me same error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: We need to write variable name which are mentioned in Data frame. I did different that was error.